# extracting index from a nested list

Tags: python, list, recursion

I would like to be able to get the index of each number in a nested list so for example i have the following list:

T = ['apple', [10, 5, ['orange']], 3]

and i would like to extract the values as such:

List of numbers: [10,5,3]
address of numbers: [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2]]

so for example, the number '3' is the third value in the list (index 2), where as the number '5' is the second value in the second list so it will be [1,1].

I've written the following recursive function with a for loop inside:

```
indices = []
List_numbers = []
Address_numbers = []

def Numbers(T):
    for index, elem in enumerate(T):
        if isinstance(elem, int):
            List_numbers.append(elem)
            Address_numbers.append(indices + [index])

        if isinstance(elem, list):
            indices.append(index)
            Fruits(elem)

    print('List of numbers: ' + str(List_numbers))
    print('Address of numbers: ' + str(Address_numbers))
```

The problem with this code, is when it reaches the last value and needs to exit the list it keeps the same index so the address is outputs is this:

```
List of numbers: [10, 5, 3]
Address of numbers: [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2, 2]]
```

I've tried everything to fix it but im honestly not sure how it would be possible to fix this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `recursive function` to extract index from nested list.
Using `recursion` you can extract index from nested list to any depth:

```
T = ['apple', [10, 5, ['orange']], 3]
total_numbers = []
indexes = []


def find_index_of_numbers(lisst, level):
    for index, value in enumerate(lisst):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            total_numbers.append(value)
            indexes.append([level, index])
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            find_index_of_numbers(value, level + 1)


find_index_of_numbers(T, 0)
print("My list--->", T)
print("Numbers--->", total_numbers)
print("Indexes--->", indexes)
```

Output

```
My list---> ['apple', [10, 5, ['orange']], 3]
Numbers---> [10, 5, 3]
Indexes---> [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this solutions its helping me alot but is theres any way possible to do this without showing that initial 0? so its like [2] instead of [0,2] ?